# iplocation.net Reports the Same Proxy, TorBrowser (tor) or Firefox (non-tor)

Tags: proxy, ip, privacy, tor

The site https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address (What is my IP?) reports an IP address, and two proxy addresses. One of the two proxy addresses is the same from TorBrowser (tor) or from Firefox (non-tor). I tried this with two different VPNs, and from different VPN servers. I haven't tried this without a VPN, as I only connect to Tor when using a VPN. This doesn't seem okay. I searched that IP address with Google, and I don't see any report of this, which I would expect if they showed that IP address as a proxy for everyone.

Comment: Details, please.

Comment: What details do you need?  You can open the URL and see what it does.  If you run tor, are you seeing that that 2nd proxy ip address is the same, tor and non-tor?

Answer (score 1):

That site www.iplocation.net is broken.

It is being hosted behind Incapsula (a competitor to CloudFlare), and one of the IP addresses it shows in its list as a "Proxy" is the Incapsula IP address which relayed the request to their backend servers. It has nothing to do with you.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm gong to wait a few days to make sure there aren't other comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I've just dived down this rabbit-hole as well, and come to the same conclusion.